# サブドメインへのリダイレクト設定について

Tags: apache, .htaccess

サイト移行時の301リダイレクト設定に関してです。

`https://example.com/sample/`というページを`https://new.example.com/sample/`へ301リダイレクトをかける場合の、.htaccessの記述方法を調べています。
なかなか検索でも載っていないので、お助けください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

尚、exmaple.com直下のディレクトリにある.htaccessに下記記述をするとエラーが起きます。

```
Redirect permanent /sample https://new.example.com/sample
```

※リダイレクト処理が解決しました※

下記のように追加記述すると反映されました。
ありがとうございます。

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

※下記追加記述※
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sample.*$

RewriteRule ^.*$ https://new.example.com/sample [R=301]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` は .conf のあるディレクトリではなくて、htmlなどのコンテンツのある場所に保存してください。例えば `/var/www/html` が ルートの場合は、`/var/www/html/.htaccess` に保存します。

Comment: 下記のように、.htaccessに追加記述することで反映できました。

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

※※下記追加記述※※
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sample.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://new.example.com/sample [R=301]
※※※※※※※※※※

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: @osamidori 解決したようでよかったです！！もしよければ、自己解決した内容を、ご自身で回答として 書き込んでもらえますか？そして、解決マークをつけてもらえれば、この質問のステータスが「解決済み」になるので、他の人が 見た人が、解決したことが わかるようになります。自分で回答するのは 推奨されておりますので 是非どうぞ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。はじめて利用するので、解決済みの仕方が分かりませんでした。

Comment: @osamidori 問題が解決した場合には、解決に至った手順等を**個別の回答**として投稿してください。「挨拶だけの回答」や、「質問文に回答を直接追記してしまう」のは推奨されません。